# How to dynamically set appengine gradle property

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-platform

How can I create a task that dynamically set app engine project id and run the `appengineDeploy` task?

On this example when I run `deployStaging` `appengineDeploy` is being executed with project 'a', how I can rewrite this code to make it run with project 'b'?

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.0.1")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

def gcpProject = 'a'

appengine {
    deploy {
        projectId = gcpProject
    }
}

task deployStaging() {
    doLast {
        gcpProject = 'b'
    }
}
deployStaging.finalizedBy appengineDeploy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a [project property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties) instead? Project properties can be passed via `-P` command line parameters:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.0.1")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

def gcpProject = project.findProperty('stageName') ?: 'a'

appengine {
    deploy {
        projectId = gcpProject
    }
}
```

Now if you just call `./gradlew appengineDeploy` the `gcpProject` variable will have the value 'a'. If you call `./gradlew appengineDeploy -PstageName=b` the `gcpProject` variable will have the value 'b'.

Comment: Tks for the answer @britter. On [this link](https://medium.com/swlh/dynamic-appengine-configurations-using-gradle-part-1-e3959a39f31b) there is also one solution similar with the one you suggested. On my case, if possible, I would like to have different tasks to avoid adding this configuration on intellij

Comment: If you really can't do this, you would have to create an additional task of type DeployTask using `task deployStage(type: DeployTask)`. Then because of the way the plugin is implemented (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/d1b0c2677b740e22395a2a969f65932a0f53ef0c/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/gradle/appengine/standard/AppEngineStandardPlugin.java#L120-L123) you need to inject your own custom deploy configuration. I really suggest going with project properties and defining a custom gradle run configuration in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by the gradle plugin folks:

```
appengine {
  deploy {
     version = "123"
     // do not define projectId here
  }
}

task deployStaging {
  dependsOn appengineDeploy
}
task deployProduction {
  dependsOn appengineDeploy
}

// here's the weird gradle logic, use at your own risk
if (project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("deployStaging")) {
  appengine.deploy.projectId = "potato-stage"
}
else if(project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("deployProduction")) {
  appengine.deploy.projectId = "tomato-prod"
}
```